# Почему не работает полиморфизм с дженериками?

Tags: java, ооп, generics, полиморфизм

для

```
Comparable<BigDecimal> c = new BigDecimal("");
```

все отлично, но для

```
List<Comparable<BigDecimal>> l = new ArrayList<BigDecimal>();
```

начинает ругаться на не соответсвтие типов

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**«Дженерики» инвариантны**.

Приведем пример:

```
List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
List<Number> nums = ints; // compile-time error. Проблема обнаружилась на этапе компиляции
nums.set(2, 3.14);
assert ints.toString().equals("[1, 2, 3.14]");
```

Если взять список целых чисел, то он не будет являться ни подтипом типа Number, ни каким-либо другим подтипом. Он является только подтипом самого себя.

```
То есть List <Integer> — это List<Integer> и ничего больше.
```

Компилятор позаботится о том, чтобы переменная ints, объявленная как список объектов класса Integer, содержала только объекты класса Integer и ничего кроме них. На этапе компиляции производится проверка, и у нас в рантайме уже ничего не упадет.

Казалось бы, удобно было бы использовать подход приведенный выше, но дженерики сделаны так, чтобы, если код компилируется, то в рантайме — не должно быть исключительных ситуаций.

Компилятор не даст нам даже сделать такое:

```
List<Number> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Рассмотрим абстрактный код (как пример):

```
List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List list = integers;
List<Number> numbers = integers; // error
numbers.add(4.5d);

Integer i = numbers.get(0); // error
Integer i = numbers.get(0); // ClassCastException
```

Ошибка выводится сразу в двух строках.

В первом:

> java: incompatible types: java.util.List cannot be
>   converted to java.util.List

Что в принципе и ожидалось, но даже если бы это сработало, то информация о типе в листе numbers стерлась бы (стирание типов). Следовательно, мы бы не смогли взять из этой коллекции Integer, а вместо этого получили бы **ClassCastException**.

Answer (score 5):

`ArrayList<T> implements List<T>`, т.е. чтобы работал полиморфизм, нужно, чтобы тип и в ArrayList и в List был один и тот же. Для таких случаев есть generic wildcards.

```
List<? extends Comparable<BigDecimal>> l = new ArrayList<BigDecimal>();
```